# useState React Implementations

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-state

I saw two different implementations for useState and I want to know the difference.

```
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  ...
  // First: using var from useState
  setCount(count + 1);
  // Second: using prevState in a function
  setCount(count => count + 1);
```

Comment: From the docs: "If the new state is computed using the previous state, you can pass a function to setState. The function will receive the previous value" https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Answer (score 1):

```
// Will not be re fired until UI is re rendered e.g you have a cart and you wanna increment the number of products in the cart. That way you can ensure that in case the user hit the increment button twice by accident the number wont increment twice before it‘s re rendered
 setCount(count + 1); 

// Will update count twice unless a rerendered were completed
setCount(count => count + 1);
```